# Como Inserir um parametro do meu sistema em uma URL externa

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Então, nos temos um site que ao passar o código de um usuário, ele mostra a localização do mesmo.

Exemplo da URL:

```
http://npaa1215.example.com/gisb_prod/integration/coordUser.aspx?codUser=30071665&zoom=15
```

Na URL nos podemos passar o parâmetro `codUser`.

Na minha aplicação eu tenho esses códigos e gostaria de inserir no campo  codUser

No exemplo o site da apontando pro usuário `codUser=30071665`

Essa é a minha **Barcoviewmodel**

```
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Registro SAP")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
    public int SapId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tancagem Água")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
    public int CapacidadeAgua { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tancagem óleo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
    public int CapacidadeOleo { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
    public int Velocidade { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o campo E-mail")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Máximo {0} caracteres")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Preencha um E-mail válido")]
    [Display(Name ="E-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

E no meu controler eu pensei em fazer algo assim:

```
    string url = http://npaa1215.example.com/gisb_prod/integration/coordUser.aspx?codUser={0}&zoom=15;
    private string GetLocation(BarcoViewModel barcoViewModel)
    {
        return string.Format(url, barcoViewModel.SapId);
    }
```

Mas não vai funcionar, alguém teria um exemplo de como eu inserir isso na *view*?

Como eu faria pro método da ***controller*** retorna essa *url* com o parâmetro?

********EDIT*******

Baseado na resposta dos colegas

Esse é o meu código da Controller:

```
   http://npaa1215.example.com/gisb_prod/integration/coordUser.aspx?codUser=30071665&zoom=15

   [HttpGet]
    private string GetLocation(BarcoViewModel barcoViewModel)
    {
        return string.Format(url, barcoViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public RedirectResult RedirectTo(BarcoViewModel barcoViewModel)
    {
        string destination = GetLocation(barcoViewModel);
        return RedirectPermanent(destination);
    }
```

Esse é a View

```
    <a href="@Url.Action("RedirectTo","Barcos", new { id = item.SapId })" class="btn btn-danger">
     <span title="Excluir" class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span>
    </a>
```

Só que mesmo fazendo essas adições, eu ainda recebo o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A Url que você quer retornar é da sua própria aplicação?

Comment: O que exatamente você está querendo fazer? redirecionar para esse endereço ou simplesmente retornar a string?

Comment: @VictorLaio essa url é de outro sistema, ela ja ta rodando na internet, a minha ideia é inserir o"sapId" da minha viewmodel, no campo "codUser". ai o usuário ao clicar no botão, por exemplo ele é redirecionado para esse site, só que com o parâmetro q eu passei.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo redirecionar para esse site, só que passando no campo "codeUser" a propriedade "sapId" do meu sistema. Ai ao usuário clicar em um botão, por exemplo, ele redireciona o usuário para esse site.

Comment: Coloquei 2 soluções possiveis pra vc amigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma action na sua controller do tipo `RedirectResult`

```
[HttpGet]
public RedirectResult RedirectTo(int id)
{
    string location = GetLocation(id);
    return RedirectPermanent(location);
}

string url = "http://npaa1215.example.com/gisb_prod/integration/coordUser.aspx?codUser={0}&zoom=15";
private string GetLocation(int id)
{
    return string.Format(url, id);
}
```

**E na sua View**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("RedirectTo","Barcos", new { id = item.SapId })" class="btn btn-danger">
  <span title="Excluir" class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Com esse `RedirectPermanent()` consigo colocar URLs que não sejam da minha app? Por exemplo: RedirectPermanent("http://www.google.com")?

Comment: Sim, você consegue.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Entendi. Fiz o sugerido e acrescentei na view o código:
href="@Url.Action("RedirectTo","Barcos", new { id = item.SapId })"
Mas da aquele erro padrão: "Erro Servidor no Aplicativo '/'", 
alguma sugestão?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo ok, vou editar a perguntar e te mostrar como to fazendo, inclusive na view

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Pronto, editei a pergunta com as alterações e com o erro.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Vi, obrigado pelos feedbacks.
O "return string.Format(url, id)" ta retornando o seguinte erro: "A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.'" Saberia oq pode ser?

Comment: @Jhensen Faça o debug e veja onde você errou

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Resolvi, obrigado pela ajuda, irei marcar como resposta.

Comment: @Jhensen Resolveu?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Resolveu sim, tá redirecionado pro site, substituindo o código como eu queria. Foi erro meu, seu código está correto.

Answer (score 0):

De um jeito bem simples pode ser feito diretamente no JavaScript (Você pode alterar o método para receber o parametro do id se necessário também.):

```js
  function AbrirUrl() {
    var url = 'http://npaa1215.example.com/gisb_prod/integration/coordUser.aspx?codUser={0}&zoom=15';
    url = url.replace('{0}', '@Model.SapId');

    window.location.href = url;
  }
```

Você pode criar um método então no controller onde vai tratar a URL e retornar um JSON:

```js
  string url = "http://npaa1215.example.com/gisb_prod/integration/coordUser.aspx?codUser={0}&zoom=15";
  
  [HttpGet]
  private JsonResult GetLocationURL(long SapID)
  {
    return Json(new { URL = string.Format(url, SapID) });
  }
```

Agora na sua View é só adicionar a requisição pro método fazendo ele abrir a URL:

```js
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetLocationURL", "SEU_CONTROLLER")',
    method: "GET",
    data: { SapID: @Model.SapId },
    success: function (result) {
      window.location.href = result.URL;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Entendi, mas e se eu fosse passar via url.action.
Um exemplo:
<a href="@Url.Action("GetLocationURL", "Barcos", new {id = item.sapId})" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <span title="Detalhes" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </a>

Minha idéia é colocar um botão na tabela que lista os usuários, pra redirecionar o usuário pra essa url

Comment: Você não consegue direcionar o navegador para uma URL externa diretamente do Controller até onde sei.

Comment: Blz, to tentando implementar o json
Mas parece que não da pra acessar o @Model dentro do script, parece que ele não encontra o parametro sapId, na verdade ele não ta encontrando nenhum parâmetro da model
IEnumerable<BR.Rve.Application.ViewModels.BarcoViewModel>

Comment: Então, ele só vai acessar o @Model se o script estiver no cshtml... Pq nao usa o método simples do js que postei la em primeiro?